# Unzip a file using Apache Camel UnZippedMessageProcessor

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

Trying to unzip a file using Apache Camel, I tried the example given in http://camel.apache.org/zip-file-dataformat.html but I can't find **UnZippedMessageProcessor** class. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipFileDataFormat;

public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
    zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);
    from("file:src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/dataformat/zipfile/")
            .unmarshal(zipFile).split(body(Iterator.class)).streaming()
            .process(new UnZippedMessageProcessor()).end();

}
}
```

Anyone tried to do this or have another way to unzip a file through a Camel route?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you got the camel-zipfile dependency on your classpath? ( described at the bottom of your link)

Comment: Yes I have. I've already checked the camel-zipfile jar but I can't find the class in it, or in any other jar though.

Comment: You need to write the UnZippedMessageProcessor yourself, I guess it is just an example name.

Comment: Instead of using zipSplitter, I am doing it the same way you are, except that instead of the .process(new UnZippedMessageProcessor()), I am just giving the destination directory where I expect to see the unzipped files - .to("file:/destDirForUnzippedFiles/")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also define the route like this, you can find the **ZipSplitter** inside of camel-zipfile.

```
 from("file:src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/dataformat/zipfile?consumer.delay=1000&noop=true")
  .split(new ZipSplitter())
  .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class).to("mock:processZipEntry")
  .end()
```

Comment: That didn't unzip the file into a directory. But I doubt that Camel's ZipFile dataformat can unzip a file into a directory directly. We should get through streams to create directory and the files in it.

Comment: No, ZipSplitter doesn't unzip the files into directories. It just help camel to consume the input stream of the zipped files.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier to figure out if the documentation wasn't so sparse. First, like someone else mentioned, the docs assume that you'll write your own `Processor` implementation. A simple one looks like this:

```
public class ZipEntryProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
    }

}
```

If you debug the `process` method, you'll see that the body of the input message is of type `ZipInputStreamWrapper`, which extends the Java class `BufferedInputStream`. That's useful information because it tells you that you could probably use Camel's built-in data transformations so that you don't have to write your own processor.

So here's how you consume a zip file and extract all of its entries to a directory on the file system:

```
from("file:src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/dataformat/zipfile/")
            .split(new ZipSplitter())
                .streaming()
                .to("file://C:/Temp/")
                .end();
```

It's actually ridiculously simple. Also, you have to make sure you understand the file component URI syntax properly too. That tripped me up the most. Here's an excellent [blog post](https://fabian-kostadinov.github.io/2016/01/10/reading-from-and-writing-to-files-in-apache-camel/) about that topic.