# How do I process a zip file with Camel using the Spring DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to monitor a directory for zip files and then individually process the files in the zip file using Camel and the Spring DSL.  Is something like the following possible?

```
<camel:route>
  <camel:from uri="file:/src/Path/"/>
  <camel:split streaming="true">
    <zipSplit/>
    <camel:to uri="bean:fileProcessor?method=processStream"/>
  </camel:split>
</camel:route>
```

Ok so I found that the following works for a zip file containing one file but the question is how can a zip file containing more than one file be processed?

```
<bean id="zipFileDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipFileDataFormat"/>

<camel:camelContext>
    <camel:contextScan/>
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="file:///C:/testSrc/?delay=6000&noop=true&idempotent=false"/>
        <camel:unmarshal ref="zipFileDataFormat"/>
        <camel:to uri="file:///C:/testDst"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Note that the file is not being sent to a bean for processing just unzipped into another directory.

Comment: just asking, the route that have you posted is that valid, or are you depicting your expectations/requirements ?

Comment: maybe refer to this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839379/unzip-a-file-using-apache-camel-unzippedmessageprocessor ?

Comment: it is more around the requirements, it is modeled on another route that's currently working for me

Comment: yes I saw the Java DSL examples, but the rest of the applications use the Spring DSL and we need to be consistent for our support staff

Comment: you can write the same in spring also, changes would be minimal. Try writing a java dsl first make it work, then maybe you can convert it to spring dsl. { i m too lazy to do this myself and give you an answer :) }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works.  Note the log element will give you the details.

```
<bean id="zipFileDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipFileDataFormat">
    <property name="usingIterator" value="true"/>
</bean>

<camel:camelContext>
    <camel:contextScan/>
    <camel:route id="unzipMultipleFiles">
        <camel:from uri="file:///C:/testSrc/?delay=30000&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotent=false"/>
        <camel:unmarshal ref="zipFileDataFormat"/>
        <camel:split streaming="true">
            <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
            <camel:to uri="log:org.apache.camel?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true&amp;multiline=true"/>
            <camel:to uri="file:///C:/testDst"/>
        </camel:split>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```