# Using ZipSplitter in Apache Camel Spring DSL

Tags: java, spring, zip, apache-camel

I would like to know how to use ZipSplitter from camel-zipfile in Spring DSL. I have been trying different approaches based on this post [Unzip a file using Apache Camel UnZippedMessageProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839379/unzip-a-file-using-apache-camel-unzippedmessageprocessor) but I am not able to figure out how to do in Spring. Also, I have not found any examples about this.

I have something like this:

```
<bean id="zipSplitter" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipSplitter" />

...

<split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true">
    <?????>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <to uri="file:foo" />
</split>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  to hold the reference of expression just like this

```
<bean id="zipSplitter" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipSplitter" />

...

<split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true">
    <ref>zipSplitter</ref> 
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <to uri="file:foo" />
</split>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Camel 2.13.0, using `parallelProcessing="true"` and unzipping a .zip file containing 10 xml files around 10Kb each, it throws a couple of exceptions:

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:375) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]

and on retry:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:66) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:181) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:375) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]

I've found a workaround, removing the `parallelProcessing="true"` attribute:

```
<route id="ConsumeZipFiles">
    <from uri="file:src/test/resources/input/zip?noop=true&amp;delay=30000" />
    <split streaming="true">
        <ref>zipSplitter</ref> 
        <to uri="file:target/output" />
    </split>
</route>
```